# Type Vector<T> in MathNet add in list ,each of member in list all change value

Tags: c#

I want to use list to save vector type,but i find when i add a vector member in list, all the member is changed.

```
List<Vector<double>> sensorDataList = new List<Vector<double>>();
sensorDataList.Add(sensorData); //sensorData is a vector type
```

Comment: What do you mean by "all the member is changed" ?

Comment: this *sounds* more like a problem in whatever is populating the data; since `Vector<T>` is a mutable class (in MathNet), most likely you have a loop that overwrites the same vector object repeatedly, instead of creating a new vector per logical row. Can you show enough code to *actually demonstrate the problem*, i.e. a single block of code that populates the data and demonstrates "all the member is changed"

Comment: as an example of what I mean: here's enough code to show it working fine: `var sensorData = Vector<double>.Build.DenseOfArray(new double[] { 1, 2, 3 }); var sensorDataList = new List<Vector<double>>(); sensorDataList.Add(sensorData); Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", sensorDataList[0].ToArray())); Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", sensorData.ToArray()));` - so: what are you doing differently that behaves unexpectedly?

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks,Consistent with what you describe.I have solved the problem.